# ! ( NULL || 0 || '' ) if condition in PHP at the same time

Tags: php, if-statement

If I want to check the variable I need to do this:

```
if ( $i != '' || $i != 0 || $i != NULL ) {

   // ...do some code

}
```

Could these 3 checks be somehow merged into 1 via some php function or a trick?

Comment: yes !empty() will work.  See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: You should post as an answer @Jacob

Comment: Wait.... can $i be all three of these at once ('', 0, NULL)?? This if statement looks like it is always true.

Comment: @MillieSmith Good point, I generally wouldn't use *OR* with `!=`

Comment: This could make a difference if you're querying a DB and checking for `NULL` as a string in a column.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A column with `"NULL"` as the value is likely already wrong .. hopefully that nonsense can be avoided.

Comment: Depends on how the DB/column(s) are set up. Some have `NULL`, some have `NOT NULL` @user2864740

Comment: @Fred-ii- A column with `"NULL"` is already [likely] broken. It should be NOT NULL .. with no `NULL` values or it should be NULLABLE with (possibly) `NULL` values. If there are `"NULL"` values in a column (it doesn't matter if it's nullable or not) then that should be fixed before worrying about anything else. (`"NULL"` values can be inserted all-to-easily by manually building an SQL string instead of properly using placeholders; this should be fixed!)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!empty($i)) {
    // ... do some code
}
```

Please see http://php.net/manual/function.empty.php

Comment: @user2989475 I had to check, but yes

Comment: @user2989475 yes, it will type convert.  The link I posted in my comment above has all of the items that empty works with. "0" is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

All of them are actualy `false`y. So you could do

```
if(!$i) {

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

I should probably elaborate on why the OP has some bad assumptions. The list of things PHP will evaluate to `false` is long

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

This is where equivalency comes into play. It's a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The OP has this

```
if ( $i != '' || $i != 0 || $i != NULL )
```

All three are actually the same test. Take this code

```
$i = 0;
if($i == '') {
    echo 'true';
}
if($i == 0) {
    echo 'true';
}
if($i == NULL) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

All three statements will echo out. So if you want to know if `$i` is actually `NULL` or `false` as opposed to `0` (and [some functions](https://www.php.net/strpos) will return both) you have to use a different operator. `===` is used to see if the two are equivalent and not simply equal.

```
$i = 0;
if($i == NULL) {
    echo 'true'; //This will succeed
}
if($i === NULL) {
    echo 'true'; //This will NOT succeed
}
```